# Can Managed Identity of a Azure Function have access across multiple subscriptions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-managed-identity

We have created a Azure Timer Function that monitors activities of various resources of one subscription. Now we want to update it so that it can have access to more than one subscription.

Is it possible to achieve the level of access for the managed identity of Azure Function?

Answer (score 8):

Yes.
Managed identities exist in the Azure AD tenant as service principals, and can thus be assigned access to any subscription connected to that Azure AD tenant.

If the subscriptions are connected to different Azure AD tenants, then no.

Comment: If I understand correctly, that would mean user assigned managed identities cannot be used across subscriptions. Is that accurate?

Comment: No, you should be able to use them in different subscriptions, as long as those subscriptions are under the same Azure AD (Entra ID) tenant.